# Knockout with Pager.js data not binding

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, knockout.js, pagerjs

I am new with knockout JS and Pager.JS I am trying to bind data on ajax request. but its not working.

```
define(['knockout', 'pager'], function (ko, pager) {
var viewModel = {
    preview: function(page) {
        pager.navigate('#Preview');
    }
};

$.getJSON(contentUrl + 'api/Data/UserData', function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    formViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, viewModel );
    ko.applyBindings(formViewModel);
});

pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
pager.start();
});


<div data-bind="page: {id: 'start', title: 'User Details'}" class="off">
<form id="userDetails" name="userDetails" method="post">

    <div class="details">
        <div class="columns clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">User Name</div>
                <span data-bind="text: Name" class="txt"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div for="Address" class="label">User Address</div>
                <span data-bind="text: Address" class="txt"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-buttons hide-for-print">
        <a href="#Preview" data-bind="click: preview" class="btn" id="preview">Preview</a>
    </div>

</form>
</div>

<div data-bind="page: {id: 'Preview', title: 'User Details| Preview'}" class="off">
Preview page

</div>

<div data-bind="page: {id: '?'}" class="off">
<h2>Error</h2>
<p>The page you requested does not exist.</p>
<p><a data-bind="page-href: '../'" id="">Go back</a></p>
</div>
```

I don't understand what am I missing. If I don't make an ajax request and bind the hardcoded data the binding works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd suggest that it's to do with calling ko.applyBindings twice, I also don't think that fromJS returns anything when you are doing an update. Equally, I don't think calling that method in the update mode will create observables on your view models, though I could be wrong there, but I've always done a "create" mapping before doing an update mapping.

I'd have done it more like this:

```
var viewModel = {};

$.getJSON(contentUrl + 'api/Data/UserData', function (data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {});
    viewModel.preview = function(page){
        pager.navigate('#Preview');
    };
});

pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
pager.start();
```